# public method called private method jasmin test in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Method which need to be test

```
public closeConfigOpe(data: any) {
   this.isConfigOpeView = false;
   this.configParam = null;
   if(data) {
      //private method is called
      this.updatePrivateMethod(data);
   }
}
```

Test Case is given below

```
it('should be called closeConfigOpe method', () => {
   let data = true;
   component.closeConfigOpe(data);
}
```

failing this test case kindly help me to how can write the test case which is having call of private method or what should be  better approch to write this kind of test cases in jasmin angular

Comment: Could you share the error msg, please?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined